# Laravel 4.2 - Select only rows where count of rows based on another query are 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I want to set up scheduled emails for recommended oil changes. To do this, I need to select from a table of line items where the last oil change was over 3 months ago. I need a condition to ignore currently selected customer rows where an oil change was purchased under 3 months ago. How would I add this condition?

```
$search_term = 'oil change';
$date = new DateTime('-3 months');

$users = $this->prospectInstance->getDatabase()->table('LineItems')
    ->join('WorkOrder', 'WorkOrder.id', '=', 'LineItems.order_id')
    ->join('Customer', 'Customer.customer_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.customer_id')
    ->where('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$search_term%")
    ->where('WorkOrder.create_date', '<=', $date)
    // this block produces errors
    ->whereNotIn('Customer.customer_id', function($query) use ($search_term, $date)
    {
        return $query->where('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$search_term%")
            ->join('WorkOrder', 'WorkOrder.id', '=', 'LineItems.order_id')
            ->join('Customer', 'Customer.customer_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.customer_id')
            ->where('WorkOrder.create_date', '>=', $date);
    })
    ->orderBy('WorkOrder.create_date', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('Customer.customer_id');
```

**Table Structure:**

```
LineItems
    order_id
    line_type

WorkOrder
    id
    customer_id
    create_date

Customer
    customer_id
```

Edit: I was able to use the advice below to use two separate queries to accomplish this, but I'd like to know if there is a single query I can create to accomplish the same result:

```
$search_term = 'oil change';
$date = new DateTime('-3 months');

$base_query = $this->prospectInstance->getDatabase()->table('LineItems')
    ->join('WorkOrder', 'WorkOrder.id', '=', 'LineItems.order_id')
    ->join('Customer', 'Customer.customer_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.customer_id')
    ->where('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$search_term%")
    ->orderBy('WorkOrder.create_date', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('Customer.customer_id');

$recent = clone $base_query;
$users = clone $base_query;

$recent->where('WorkOrder.create_date', '>', $date)
    ->select('Customer.customer_id');
$users->where('WorkOrder.create_date', '<=', $date)
    ->whereNotIn('Customer.customer_id', $recent->lists('customer_id'));
```

Comment: You'll have to join the table and column where you have records of customer's oil purchase to the current query.

Comment: I think you could just do `->whereNotIn('Customer.customer_id', [array_of_custom_ids])`

Comment: SUNNYben is right but in order for anyone to answer this more thoroughly you need to provide more information about your table structure and/or where the purchased date information is.

Comment: @chasenyc I've added the relevant table structure to the question if that helps. @Ohgodwhy Is it possible/prudent to use an anonymous function in place of `[array_of_custom_ids]`? What should be returned from that function?

Comment: @Shane are the LineItems the purchases? I am a little unclear if they had a work order created in the last 3 months for an oil change, they are not included but they could have purchased an oil change in the last three months but not received it yet?

Comment: @chasenyc Correct - `LineItems` are individual products purchased in a `WorkOrder` (oil change, new sparkplugs, tire rotation, etc). Using @Ohgodwhy's advice, I was able to split the query into two: selecting `customer_ids` where they have had an oil change in the last three months and using those ids in a `whereNotIn` condition for oil changes greater than three months. However, I'd like to learn how (or if) I can do this within a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work but is obviously not tested:

```
$users = $this->prospectInstance->getDatabase()->table('Customer')
    ->join('WorkOrder', 'WorkOrder.customer_id', '=', 'Customer.customer_id')
    ->join('LineItems', 'LineItems.order_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.id')
    ->where('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$search_term%")
    ->whereNotIn('Customer.customer_id', function($query) use ($date, $search_term)
    {
        $query->select('Customer.customer_id')
            ->from('Customer')
            ->join('WorkOrder', 'Customer.customer_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.customer_id')
            ->join('LineItems', 'WorkOrder.id', '=', 'LineItems.order_id')
            ->where('WorkOrder.create_date', '>', $date)
            ->where('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$search_term%");
    })
    ->orderBy('WorkOrder.create_date', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('Customer.customer_id');
```

Comment: Where in your query is the condition to ignore customers who have work orders with oil changes in the last three months?

Comment: `->where('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$search_term%")` returns only records which are oil changes or users who do not have any workorders(`->orWhereNull('WorkOrder.create_date')`). It filters out any of those records with dates sooner than three months with `->where('WorkOrder.create_date', '<=', $date)`

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page, exactly. Since I don't want to email customers who have had oil changes in the last 90 days, I need a condition to not select these users. The query you provided (and the query I started with) is simply not selecting users with recent oil changes. I actually need to know the users who have had recent oil changes so I can remove them from the final result if they are present. So, select users who have had an oil change 90+ days ago and who have NOT had an oil change 1-89 days ago.

Comment: Ah I see, big oversight on my part. I've added a subquery to handle that.